# Java Web Start window title problem

Tags: javafx, jnlp, java-web-start

I've written a JavaFX application that uses Java Web Start. For some reason, the window title is always "Java" (on Linux) or blank (on Windows). However, the desktop icon has the correct application title and image.

From what I've found so far, the important bit here is the information > title element in the JNLP file.

What am I missing?

NOTE: I'm happy to post my JNLP content if someone says it would be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the application title and icon for the taskbar entry are controlled by the `title` and `icons` attributes of the `Stage`.

Only the title and icon of the desktop icon are controlled by the JNLP.